# Multiple row select in Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I have googled around for this but cannot find an answer. Does anyone know if there is any support for selecting multiple rows at once (by clicking shift/control as opposed to using tick boxes)?

Answer (score 0):

I use RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX, but I imagine it is similar to MVC -- is there not a property in your RadGrid tag called "AllowMultiRowSelection"?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you or others that come accross this question: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/grid-row-selector.aspx#1163538

It is for an older version, but should still be good! It is not the same as in RadControls in ASP.NET AJAX in MVC it is not supported out of the box.